# Disable mangling with esbuild with build-angular:browser-esbuild

Tags: angular, esbuild, angular-builder

With the webpack builder we can use `NG_BUILD_MANGLE=0` to disable mangling.

But that doesn't work with the new esbuild builder.

Is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support of `NG_BUILD_MANGLE` has been added ot the CLI by [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/ba3b4ceac817c6eed76d85360c4fcb671bc79368).